# Не запускается javascript из php файла

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Есть файл index.php, в этом файле подключен javascript через

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="uk">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Fiji Travel</title>
<link href="normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="main/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="main/login.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="center">
        <!-- Header -->
        <header>
            <h1>Fiji Travel</h1>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="../index.php" class="active">Главная</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../blog/blog.php">Блог</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../gallery/gallery.php">Фото</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../about/about.php">Про нас</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../contacts/contacts.php">Контакты</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <img src="../images/img02.jpg" alt="img02" class="slide">
        </header>
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <?php require 'modules/sidebar.php'; ?>
        <!-- Content -->
        <main class="slide">
            <div>
                <h2>Добро пожаловать на Фиджи</h2>
                <img src="images/img03.jpg" alt="img03">
                <p><b>Фиджи</b> - название государства и архипелага из 332 островов, на которых это государство находится: на юго-западе Тихого океана, среди других островов и архипелагов Меланезии - правда, расстояние между этими частицами суши составляет сотни и тысячи километров. Острова архипелага Фиджи коралловые и вулканические; примерно 1/3 их нежилые, однако это и привлекает внимание желающих уединиться по разным причинам - влюбленных пар, молодоженов, романтиков и просто любителей нетронутой природы.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2>Климат Фиджи: мягкие тропики</h2>
                <img src="images/img04.jpg" alt="img04">
                <p>Климат влажный тропический, но сильной жары нет ни летом, в сезон дождей - около 26 ° C, ни в сухой сезон - около 23 ° C: здесь комфортно чувствуют себя и взрослые, и дети. Правда, бывают и более высокие температуры - 28-34 ° C, но в ночи всегда становится прохладнее.</p>
                <p>Для отдыха обычно рекомендуется выбирать период с мая по декабрь, когда дождей почти нет. Погода отличается в разных частях архипелага: так, на южных берегах основных островов дожди идут чаще и больше высокая влажность воздуха.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2>Пляжи на Фиджи</h2>
                <img src="images/img05.jpg" alt="img05">
                <p>Больше всего туристов «привлекается» на остров Вити-Леву, крупнейший в архипелаге Фиджи. Здесь любой может найти себе место по душе и по карману: есть и первоклассные отели и недорогие гостиницы. Пляжи тянутся более чем на 100 км - их называют Коралловым берегом; территория острова - более 10 000 км, и на побережье расположено множество различных курортов, от фешенебельных до тихих и незаметных. Для семейного отдыха хороший пляж Paradise, тихий и спокойный, с мелким белым песком и почти не затронутым «окультуриванием»: пальмы рядом растут прямо у берега и скрыться от жаркого солнца - не проблема, что особенно актуально для семей с детьми. Однако, об удобных головные уборы, солнечные очки и солнцезащитные средства следует позаботиться вовремя: загар на Фиджи очень красивый, но получить солнечные ожоги, в том числе и находясь в воде, можно «в два счета». Взрослые могут найти себе здесь массу развлечений, от дайвинга до рыбалки с арендой катера.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2>Экскурсии и памятные места на Фиджи</h2>
                <img src="images/img06.jpg" alt="img06">
                <p>Кажется, что памятников на Фиджи не может быть много, но их, исторических и природных, наберется немало. Сигатока - песчаные дюны, является уникальным местом: на Фиджи везде зелень, а здесь - волнообразные холмы из песка до 60 м высотой - считается, что они формировались миллионы лет. История местности не менее интересна, чем пейзаж: здесь создан археологический парк и открыт музей. Археологи находят вещи, которым около 3000 лет, а здешние захоронения еще старше.</p>
                <p>На Фиджи очень много национальных парков и заповедников, за охраной которых постоянно следят местные власти: ведь нетронутая природа - главное богатство этой небольшой и гостеприимной страны с приветливыми и веселыми жителями.</p>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div> <!-- end center -->
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div> <!-- end wrapper -->
<!-- Footer -->
<?php require 'modules/footer.php'; ?>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Я запускаю сайт через denwer. Проблема в том, что скрипт в этом файле не выполняется.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "a", function(e) {
        if ( $(this).hasClass('active') ) return;
        $("a").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(".slide").slideUp(800);
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.location.href = $(self).attr("href");
        }, 800);
    });
});
```

Когда файл был index.html, то все работало. Как это решить?

Comment: `Если без php, то все нормально работает.` - непонятна эта фраза совсем. причём тут какой-то php?

Comment: перед этим страница было index.html и все работало, но потом я подключил модули через php

Comment: а если  на время убрать все вставки `<?php require .......  ?>` но оставить всё это в php файле - то  будет работать?

Comment: нет, не работает

Comment: А в консоли случаем никаких ошибок нет?

Comment: в консоле тоже все чисто

Comment: заметил что если сайт подвисает, то javascript код начинает работать

Comment: То что в блоке `$(document).ready(function() {//и т.д.` это контент файла `script.js`? `jquery.js` и `script.js` лежат в той же папке что и это файл? Если это `index.php`, что за линк на дерикторию выше `<a href="../index.php" class="active">Главная</a>`? Какая структура директорий вообще?